# How to show native ads with Google Mobile Ads SDK 20.5.0?

Tags: android, service, admob, ads, illegalargumentexception

I'm trying to show native test ads on my project (play-services-ads:20.5.0). I tried this way and get different errors with the same error code. Can't really figure out is it a server issue or my implementation can't fulfill SDK’s requirements. I waited more than 2 hours (SpinUp Time) but it doesn't work.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        MobileAds.initialize(getApplicationContext());
        Log.d("him", "SDK initialized");

        AdLoader adLoader = new AdLoader.Builder(getApplicationContext(), "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2247696110")
                .forNativeAd(new NativeAd.OnNativeAdLoadedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onNativeAdLoaded(@NonNull NativeAd nativeAd) {
                        Log.d("him", "NativeAdLoaded");

                        NativeTemplateStyle styles = new
                                NativeTemplateStyle.Builder().build();

                        TemplateView template = findViewById(R.id.my_template);
                        template.setStyles(styles);
                        template.setNativeAd(nativeAd);
                    }
                }) .withAdListener(new AdListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAdFailedToLoad(@NonNull LoadAdError adError) {
                        // Handle the failure by logging, altering the UI, and so on.

                        Log.d("him", "AdFailedToLoad error is: \n" + adError);
                    }
                })
                .build();

        adLoader.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());

    }
}
```

I'm getting two types error one is from physical device which is this:

```
  "Code": 0,
  "Message": "Unable to obtain a JavascriptEngine.",
  "Domain": "com.google.android.gms.ads",
  "Cause": "null",
  "Response Info": {
    "Response ID": "null",
```

And another is from emulator, which is this:

```
  "Code": 0,
  "Message": "Internal error.",
  "Domain": "com.google.android.gms.ads",
  "Cause": "null",
  "Response Info": {
    "Response ID": "hu2sYZCLOJO39QP7qIvoBw",
    "Mediation Adapter Class Name": "",
    "Adapter Responses": [
      {
        "Adapter": "com.google.ads.mediation.admob.AdMobAdapter",
        "Latency": 29,
        "Credentials": {},
        "Ad Error": {
          "Code": 0,
          "Message": "Internal error.",
          "Domain": "com.google.android.gms.ads",
          "Cause": "null"
        }
      }
```

I got another issue while using emulator which is here:

```
Exception thrown while unbinding
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service not registered: lu@bc13fba
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you have an adblock installed on that device.

Please also try this ***TEMP*** solution "it might help"  :-
in `build.gradle` app level, change the app id to:

```
        applicationId "com.google.example.gms.nativeadvancedexample"
```

and let's know if the result.

Comment: worked perfectly.

Comment: I tried another device to test the code and it worked perfectly.